# OpenCV 2.4 Unsupported format for distanceTransform

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the cv::distanceTransform() function, but get the following error at runtime:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (source
>   image must be 8uC1 and the distance map must be 32fC1 (or 8uC1 in case
>   of simple L1 distance transform)) in cvDistTransform,

However, it seems that my input mat is indeed CV_8U (its type=16, depth=0, channels=3). My output mat is declared as CV_32FC1. Offending code:

```
     //...Apply laplacian
     //Convert to CV_8U
     cv::convertScaleAbs(image_laplacian, image_laplacian);

     //Distance transform
     cv::Mat edge_distance(image_laplacian.rows, image_laplacian.cols, CV_32FC1);
     cv::distanceTransform(image_laplacian, edge_distance, CV_DIST_L2, 5);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is curious. Make sure your image is single-channel. I assumed CV_8U could cast to CV_8UC1 for grayscale images, but that's not the case

You can use `cv::cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);` to reduce the number of channels.